# Best coding practices for Express JS

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to build an application on Express JS, I am coming from Laravel and Angular skillset.

There the coding convention is that we write **functions in classes** and **implement inheritance**.
But I could not find any proper example for Express where they are using the similar methodology of oop.

Can someone please suggest a good *boilerplate* or *example* where everything is done using proper principles of oop or is it the best practice to do everything by creating functions in Express?

I have used Express Generator but it is not what I am asking about.

Comment: You could use express generator

Comment: Yes, I have used it but I am talking about the best practice of coding in the Express. as I have checked many CRUD examples and no one is implementing classes, just exporting each function. but in Laravel or Angular, we do everything in a class and implement inheritance principles.